# JQuery: addClass() not changing background on selector

Tags: jquery, addclass

im having a little trouble getting the background image to swap out on click()

```
    $('.highlight-boxes li a[class!=selected-box]').click(function() {
        $('.highlight-content').hide();
        $('.highlight-boxes li a').removeClass(); 
        $(this).addClass('box-selected');  // problem here
        var selected = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
        $('#' + selected).stop(true,true).fadeIn();

        return false;
    });
```

`console.log()` in firebug returns the correct element being clicked but `$(this).addClass('box-selected')` does not change the background of the currently clicked element.

any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Can you show the HTML this interacts with, and the CSS of .box-selected, .highlight-boxes, and the other elements? Also, you have 'selected-box' in the first line and 'box-selected' in the 4th line; is one of these wrong?

Comment: wow.  i just wasted 30 mins of my life.  "box-selected" is wrong.  its supposed to be "selected-box".  thats what i get for naming classes and images so similar. :(  sorry to waste everyones time.

thanks kevin!

Comment: @gnarf - `.removeClass()` removes all classes, see the docs: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ "If a class name is included as a parameter, then only that class will be removed from the set of matched elements. If no class names are specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed."

Comment: @Nick Craver - Oops, I looked that up right before I posted that and somehow skipped that line... Comment deleted :)